# SolrCloud - 2 nodes cluster

Tags: solr, high-availability, solrcloud, disaster-recovery

We are planning to implement **SolrCloud** in our solution (mainly for data replication reasons and disaster recovery), unfortunately some of our customers have only 2DCs - and one DC may be completely destroyed.

We are aware that running ZK in 2 locations is problematic, as ZK requires quorum. And downtime on any side with 2 ZK nodes would cause cluster failure. And cluster failure would be also triggered by network partition between locations (master will cease to be master due to quorum lost, slave can't elect himself for the same reason).

--

So our current *plan A* is to go with a single ZK for both sites and backup ZK into the other site. So if the site withou ZK dies, we are OK. If the site with ZK dies, we should be able to start new ZK from backup and reconfigure Solr.

--

We also considered *plan B* with classic master-slave replication between the sites. BUT we are using Time Routed Aliases, hence we need SolrCloud features, hence we would need also to replicate data/configuratin in ZooKeeper (not only Solr index). So this case seems only as more manual work in Solr, while we would still need to backup/restore ZK. So this plan was rejected.

--

*Plan C* may be to have 2ZK, but one with with bigger weight. This should survive partition and dead of ZK with lower weight. The first ZK node should be automatically backed up using standard cluster mechanics. But I do not even know about anyone using ZK this way...

--

Is there any smarter way, how to setup SolrCloud in 2 nodes environment? Which solution should we prefer?

We do not expect High Availability; we want to achieve disaster recovery. Administrator  intervention is expected in case of node failure, we only need to be resilient to short network glitches.

---

**Edit**: CDCR (Cross Data Center Replication) with Time Routed Aliases

We are considering to use TRA, because our data are time based, and customers are usually interested only in latest slice/partition. Without TRA, the index grows and performance degrades, more (unused/old) stuff is in index & RAM...

Here comes a problem with CDCR, according to docs, the [source&target collection parameters are required](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/cross-data-center-replication-cdcr.html#CrossDataCenterReplication_CDCR_-SourceConfiguration). But with TRA, collections are created with the same solrconfig.xml automatically (every X days/months). This problem in CDCR is [known](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-6273) (see comments), but [not resolved yet](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-8389).

Also it seems that CDCR really does not synchronize ZooKeeper (I have not found any mentions of the functionality in docs, jira and in code), which may be ok with static number of collections, but is very problematic with dynamically created collections (especially by some machinery in background outside users/developers code).

---

**Edit**: According to David (the main author of TRA), [CDCR&TRA combination is not to be supported](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-11299).

Comment: Have you looked at [Cross Data Center Replication](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/cross-data-center-replication-cdcr.html)?

Comment: Actually, I have overlooked this one in docs. It may work for us.

Comment: It's a fairly recent feature and applies to a small subset of users, so any help to document use cases and configurations will probably be appreciated as well. The solr-user mailing list is also the best place to get help, so you can reach those who are actively using it already.

Comment: The docs state that solrconfig.xml is not synchronized between sides. Do you know, if its the case only for real files on filesystem? Or does this applies also to files, which are stored as entries in ZK?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea. I've never used the feature myself.

Comment: I have added an edit about Time Routed Aliases and CDCR. It seems that these features are not very compatible.

Comment: Good point. I'd create an issue on the bug tracker (or at least a post to discuss it on solr-user) to track those issues - naming could be possible through a glob pattern or something similar in the future.

Comment: I asked solr-users (no response yet) and at umbrella epic of TRA (this effort is still in progress - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-11299)